# Trigger a loop only for 5 files in a row

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a html out of several html files, but that's not my problem because this is working fine. The Problem is, that the Code I have written so far is writing **all** the several html files into one single html, but I only want to combine 5 html into one. If the one html file, which will be generated contains more then 5 html files, then it should create a new html file and so one...get it?

Comment: I don't have a practical solution but why don't you just add a counter to your loop? Then if the counter reach 5 create a new file with the content from next 5 files in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that you want t1.html, t2.html etc.

```
idx=0
counter=0
target=
for file in *; do
    if [ $((counter%5)) -eq 0 ]; then
        idx=$((idx+1))
        target=t${idx}.html
    fi
    # write to $target
    counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a counting variable, increment it in the loop, and break after it reaches 5 using the `break` statement.

See this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html